# Compute mean curvature of geodesic ball in $n$-sphere

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, curvature, spheres, geodesic

I want to compute mean curvature of boundary of geodesic ball in $S^n$.
I can calculate mean curvature of a ball in Euclidean space $(1/R)$.
However, I cannot calculate mean curvature in Riemannian manifold.
I want to regard sphere as an ambient space (not a submanifold of Euclidean space).

More precisely, $(S^n, g)$ denote a sphere, where $g$ is the warped product metric, i.e., $g= dr^2 + sin^2 r\, g_{S^n-1}$.  We assume that $r=0$ indicate the North Pole in sphere.

There is a $n$-dimensional geodesic ball centered at the North Pole with radius $R$.  Then could I compute mean curvature of the ball at the boundary of this ball?

Comment: "geodesic ball in sphere"?

Comment: What did you tried? What tools can you use?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Yes. Geodesic ball means that \{x\in S^n | dist(N,x) = R \}, where N is the North Pole and dist(N,x) is the geodesic distance induced by the metric.

Comment: @Shanna:  Your sentence is ungrammatical.

Comment: @DiegoMath In Euclidean space, I used the fact that mean curvature is 1/n (p_1 + p_2 + \cdots + p_n), where p_i are principal curvature. Also I know that circle in Euclidean space has the curvature 1/R, which means that all p_i are 1/R. Thus, I concluded that mean curvature of a ball in Euclidean space is 1/R.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork sorry....  Is the sentence you mentioned a sentence in comment or the first sentence in the post?

Comment: As you can see from my first comment, I'm referring to the *original question*.  Obviously.  How could I be referring to anything else there??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you define $u:\mathbb{S}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ to be the distance function from the North pole, we have the mean curvatura equal to

$$H=-div\left(\frac{\nabla u}{|\nabla u|}\right).$$

Thus, for a geodesic sphere of radius R, we obtain

$$H=\cot R$$

Comment: Thanks. The formula H = -div(\grad u/ |\grad u|) comes from the fact that mean curvature is the divergence of the unit normal vector, right? Then, could I use the same formula to calculate mean curvature of a ball in any rimannian manifold?